# Lua, custom iterator - proper way to define?

Tags: lua, iterator

I'm working with a lot of data files written in Lua. Most of them is written in this manner, a "phone book" as an example:

```
data = {
    -- First Level - country
    USA = {
        -- Second level - city
        Denver = {
            -- Third level - actual entries
            {name = 'John', number = '12345'},
            -- more entries
        },
        Washington = {
            {name = 'Ann', number = '54321'},
            -- more entries
        },
        -- more cities with entries
    },
    -- more countries with cities and entries
}
```

So the fact that first level is 'Country' and second is 'City' is implicit, but it makes the data more compact.

Now, when actually searching for some data, I'd like to iterate over this data as entries **including this leveled, implicit information**.

```
-- Coroutine yielding entries including level data
function corIter(data)
    for country,l1 in pairs(data) do
        for city,l2 in pairs(l1) do
            for _,entry in pairs(l2) do
                -- Copy the entry
                local out = {}
                for k,v in pairs(entry) do
                    out[k] = v
                end
                -- Add level properties
                out.country = country
                out.city = city
                coroutine.yield(out)
            end
        end
    end
end

-- Iterate over the entries
local cor = coroutine.create(corIter)
local _, entry = coroutine.resume(cor, data)
while entry do
    -- Handle the entry, has 'name', 'number', 'country' and 'city' keys
    table.print(entry) -- (custom print function I use)

    -- Get the next one
    _, entry = coroutine.resume(cor)
end
```

But I think this approach may be bad, since it keeps a whole thread alive just to iterate over a damn table in a specific way.

Is there any other "obvious" solution to this? The key there is performance and ease of use. I don't exactly need a general solution (for arbitrary numbers of "levels" inside data table), but this all in all fells like a hack.

Comment: Could you give an example of the query you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function phones(d)
   local cn, c, tn, t, i
   return
      function()
         local a
         repeat
            if tn then
               a, i = t[i], i+1
               if not a then
                  i, tn, t = 1, next(c, tn)
               end
            else
               cn, c = next(d, cn)
               i, tn, t = 1, next(c or {})
            end
         until a or not cn
         return cn, tn, a
      end
end

for country, town, abonent in phones(data) do
   print(country, town, abonent.name, abonent.number)
end
```

Comment: This may be a bit more compact than I like, but I think I can see the general gist of the method, thanks. Also liking the multiple return instead of mashing data together like I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom iterator in Lua, no need to use a coroutine. Iterators are functions that when called, return the next element from your structure (you can use any structure you want).

An iterator for your example would be something like that:

```
function corIter(data)
    local itOut = {}

    for country,l1 in pairs(data) do
        for city,l2 in pairs(l1) do
            for _,entry in pairs(l2) do
                -- Copy the entry
                local out = {}
                for k,v in pairs(entry) do
                    out[k] = v
                end

                out.country = country
                out.city = city

                table.insert(itOut,out)
            end
        end
    end

    local i = 0
    return function()
        i = i + 1
        return itOut[i]
    end
end
```

The anonymous function returned by 'corIter' will return the next element from your data. Note that when we copy the entries to another table using 'pairs' to iterate over them, nothing guarantees that the order of the entries will maintain as the original one.

So now you can use this code to print the entries:

```
for entry in corIter(data) do
    print(entry) -- this is a table
    for k,v in pairs(entry) do
        print(k,v) -- these are the actual values
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I understand correctly, this keeps a duplicate of the data table as an upvalue of the iterator function, right? It's all very clear and straightforward, nice :)

Answer (score 1):

@Egor's answer is excellent since it defines [a lua iterator](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html) instead of collecting the data into a table. Iterators have several benefits:

- Abort iteration without paying extra cost. When finding the first match, you don't always traverse the whole data set.
- More resilient to changes in the data. If the iteration changes another client's phone number, we won't return stale data.
- Doesn't require creating many temporary tables. Less gc pressure.

However, I found it too terse to follow. I've reworked it to use more descriptive names and fewer compound statements.

```lua
local function phones(phonebook)
    local country_name, country_t, city_name, city_t, i
    return function()
        local client_t
        repeat
            if city_name then
                client_t = city_t[i]
                i = i+1
                if not client_t then
                    i = 1
                    city_name, city_t = next(country_t, city_name)
                end
            else
                country_name, country_t = next(phonebook, country_name)
                i = 1
                city_name, city_t = next(country_t or {})
            end
        until client_t or not country_name
        return country_name, city_name, client_t
    end
end

local data = {
    USA = {
        Denver = {
            {name = 'John', number = '12345'},
            {name = 'Johaan', number = '13336'},
        },
        Washington = {
            {name = 'Ann', number = '54321'},
            {name = 'Ana', number = '53132'},
        },
    },
}
for country, town, client in phones(data) do
    print(country, town, client.name, client.number)
end
```

Output:

```
USA Washington  Ann 54321
USA Washington  Ana 53132
USA Denver  John    12345
USA Denver  Johaan  13336
```